# Custom WP_Query not working (listing featured articles + popular articles)

Tags: wordpress, posts, wordpress-featured-image

I am Wordpress beginer and I want to set multiple queries on a page that lists my posts.

## Featured posts

I have front page that lists featured posts from all categories,
Categories pages that lists featured posts from current category

Q: Is it better to use *My featured posts* new category name or to set *sticky post* (under public - publish options) for posts I want to feature on front page and on categories pages? Every post already have his own category like *News* so the *My featured posts* will be the second category.

## Query

Let's suppose I'm using category name for featured posts (but then i got permalink to My featured posts category (*site/my-featured-posts/2013/07.....*) which I don't want (so maybe sticky posts are better solution)

I'm trying to setup query to list featured posts but only from *standard* post type, not *gallery* or *video*

```
    <?php
    $arg = array(
         'cattegory_name' => 'my-featured-category',
         'posts_per_page' => 5,
         'nopaging' => true,
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    $featured= new WP_Query($arg);

    if ($featured->have_posts()):
            while ($featured->have_posts()) :
                  $featured->the_post();

    ?>
```

and then below  the_title(); ..... and so on

What I get is all articles from all categories.

Q: Also, how to I get popular articles based on views and number of comments for the last day?

Q: How to list posts which have post format *video*?

Q: Are there any online tools that build wp_query based on criteria?

Thank you.

Comment: It's `category_name`, not `cattegory_name`

Comment: funny, but this seems to correct my issue, tired eyes caused this :-) Thanks. Do you know answers to my other questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can also set posts as "featured" using a tag. You can then use `tag=featured` with WP_Query to get posts tagged with a certain tag ("featured" in this example).

As for your additional questions...

**Q1**: You can save page views to a flat file or to the WordPress database. Once I used the database to store a UNIX-timestamp as traditional WP post meta for each post page view. As it was a timestamp, I could calculate the age of the page view easily (and I could also run SQL queries to remove post meta that was older than a certain timespan).

Comments can be queried by time ordering too. See [WP_Comment_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query).

Of course there are plugins that can do this for you, but for me they included useless bloat I did not need.

**Q2**: For querying post formats, use the query variable called `tax_query` as *GATEKeeper* did in a WP support question: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-formats#post-2034414.

**Q3**: A google query returned a thing called *[The WordPress Query Generator](http://wpquerygenerator.com/)*.